# echo updated values instead of old values

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

How do I echo the latest values in column1? The below code echos the values before the update.

```
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$Student = $line["calss8"];

$querySf = "SELECT SUM(ABC) AS val1 FROM tbl1 WHERE student = '$Student'"; 
$resultSf = mysql_query($querySf); 
$rSf = mysql_fetch_array($resultSf); 
$totalSf = $rSf['val1']; 
$totTMonth = $totalSf;

mysql_query("UPDATE tbl4 SET column1 = $totTMonth WHERE student = '$Student' LIMIT 1");
}


echo $line["column1"].",,";
```

Comment: How about `echo $totTMonth, ',,';`? Also, please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @Phil I know. But I'm looking for a way to echo the latest values from the database.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to perform another `SELECT` query

Comment: how many of those latest values ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you'll have to make a separate query to see what was just updated.  I mean,  run your select, perform your update, then do another select.  You can get general information like how many rows were updated, but I don't think you can get specific information like the changed values in a column.  Phil was right in suggesting that you should just print out the '$totTMonth' value since that is what you are updating your column with.  That would be less overhead than doing another query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem starts before the code above. This code line will display the select results :`echo $line["column1"].",,";`.  The variable `$line` is set before the code above. My solution is to do the following:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT column1 FROM student ..."); /* I insert the select query here */

While($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo $row['column1'].",,";
}
```